# Does the pattern of gaps affect the estimation results?

Tags: panel-data, missing-data

I have a panel data covering around 300 cities. My dependent variable is matched from some other micro transaction data and hence suffers from missing value (could due to matching failure, but the original dataset is too large, it's not feasible for me to check by hand). The consequence is for some cities, the panel pattern is **"near balanced"** but for the other cities, the pattern is **strongly imbalanced** across the sample period. Then the question comes, assuming the matching failure is random, does the different gap patterns affect the estimation results, and should I just keep those "near balanced" cities. If the matching failure is not random and due to some potential "unobservable" factors, what should I do to take care of this issue. Is there any literature (both theoretical and empirical) engage in this problem? thank you for your advice.